# How to force USB to use same device ID instead of new one?

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I am having some trouble in automating the task. I am testing some android based mobiles in Linux machine. The automation script uses the device ID under `/dev/bus/usb/001/"053"` it will be always under bus `001` only. But the `dev` will be random like if I insert one mobile then the `dev` ID will be `053`, if remove and insert it again then the `dev` ID will be `054`.

The problem is, when some tests runs on the device and if device gets rebooted then new `dev` ID is showing for the rebooted one and my scripts failing due to new `dev` ID.

Is there any way to force USB devices to use same `dev` ID instead of new one, so that there will be no issues to my tests even after device reboots?

Comment: It might be helpful with some more information about how this script it working. There might be other ways to solve your problem than what you are asking for directly.

Comment: The script is nothing but a monkey random events.. When ever scripts starts it will bound with "/dev/bus/usb/001/"053" and starts running and capturing logs. About the problem i have already explained in above.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible to force a particular ID. You may instead find it useful to dynamically identify the device ID you want to bind your script to.

```
devid=/dev/bus/usb/$(lsusb | grep <yourdevice> | cut -d":" -f1 | cut -d" " -f2,4 --output-delimiter="/")
```

^ where `<yourdevice>` is something appropriately unique to identify your device.

You would then be able to use `$devid` where you previously used `/dev/bus/usb/001/053`.